# How can i attach images in a loop ? (FLTK)

Tags: c++, image, loops, graphics, fltk

I'm writing a program that reads image inputs and labels (and their coordinates ), saves them on vectors, and places them on an empty canvas in the end. So I made this loop to attach all the images on the screen and my result is always a blank screen. I have checked in case the vectors don't register but they are always working so its some problem in my loop.
(FLTK also doesn't have any problems)

The loop:

```
Simple_window win(Point(0,0),1400,900,"Collage"); 
for(int i=0;i<imgnamevec.size();++i){
    Text t(Point(xlblvec[i]+ximgvec[i],ylblvec[i]+yimgvec[i]), imglblvec[i]);
    t.set_font(Graph_lib::Font::times_bold);
    t.set_font_size(50);
    t.set_color(0);
    win.attach(t);
    Image im(Point(ximgvec[i],yimgvec[i]),imgnamevec[i]);
    win.attach(im);}
    cout << endl;
     
    

    win.wait_for_button();     
}
```

xlblvec[i],imgnamevec[i] contain the label text and the image name

xlblvec[i],ylblvec[i],ximgvec[i],yimgvec[i] contain the label coordinates and the image coordinates

Comment: I don't know if the data is copied when `attach` is called, but if not the items being attached are local variables that only exist during the iteration of the loop when they are created and they are destroyed before the next iteration.

Comment: so what do you propose to put instead of that? Pointers?

Comment: `struct Item { Text text; Image image; };` Create an Item, fill in the blanks, stick it in a vector. Make 2 different vectors if you want. *shrug* It seems like you have somewhere around 6 parallel vectors now so two more won't kill you. Personally I'd put that data in a struct and pass it to the Item constructor to initialize the Text and Image members. You could also use `emplace_back` to avoid a copy.